# Can I append data from controller to url and still render same page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple MVC application that presents an IQ test to the person.

I have a controller call **TestMyIQController** and on this controller I have three action methods and corresponding to three views.

1) Index.cshtml

2) Questions.cshtml

3) Score.cshtml

On the first page `localhost:12345/TestMyIQ/Index` of the application I ask the user to input their First and Last name and click button Next to go to second page.

On the second page of the application `localhost:12345/TestMyIQ/Questions` I present a few multiple choice questions and I have the user select True/False for each question. Once the user complete all the question she can click button Submit to see her IQ score.

On the final score page `localhost:12345/TestMyIQ/Score` I show the score via a `ViewBag` object.

However, I want to know how to modified the `final page url` so that I can append the `First Name` of the user? For example if the person name is John Doe then I want my final score url will be like this `localhost:12345/TestMyIQ/Score?firstname=John`.

Note it is not necessary to append the First Name to all other url...because I only want it on the final score page.

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Considering you received the first name in the Questions action, and added as a property of your model, you can add it to your form as a hidden field:

**Questions.cshtml**

```
using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserFirstName);
    // rest of form
}
```

**TestMyIQController**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Question(QuestionModel model)
{
    // form processing
    return RedirectToAction("Score", new{ firstName = model.UserFirstName })
}
```

Because in the Question page you stored it as a hidden field, it will only show up in the url of the score page.

But keep in mind that while this is ok if you're learning and just want to do some cool stuff to show your friends, this isn't the best way to handle all of this.

**EDIT** to add more info on the problems of using this method.

The negative is that anyone can change the URL. Nothing stops me from changing `?firstName=foo` to `?firstName=bar`. Second, names can contain invalid characters for URLs, which will need to be encoded. Third, it's overall bad design.

There are better ways to handle this, but it depends on the what you need from it. Will the users be able to share the url? If not, you can add it to the `Session`. This is definitely easier to implement in your current design. If they'll do, you could store the result in a SQL table, and share the url as `?scoreId=f88f9426-04d7-4ae2-8e15-a4bbd8d6faad`.

Comment: Hi, what is negative about this method? And, how ca I make it better?

Comment: Sorry, I've been on vacation and haven't seen your comment before. I've edited my answer.

Comment: how can I receive the "first name" in the score actionresult method?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your needs, but you dont have to store the name in url, you can use for example session variable, but if you insist on it being on url, why not just redirect(urlWithParameter).

For a good listing of possibilities, see
[Msprogrammer](http://msprogrammer.serviciipeweb.ro/2012/01/15/usual-methods-to-transfer-data-from-page-to-page-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Answer (score 0):

Session may be choice to store the name and retrieve it on the score page.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(UserModel model)
{
    // save the name 
    Session["FirstName"] = model.FirstName;

    return RedirectToAction("Questions")
}
```

On the score method, retrieve the name from session

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Score(ScoreModel model)
{
    // save the name 
    string firstName = (string)Session["FirstName"];

    return RedirectToAction("Index")
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: why RedirectToAction("Index") in Score?

Comment: I just put it for the sake of code complete. You can change it to whatever you want.

Comment: but how will this show on the URL of the Score page?